# ASP.NET Membership.ValidateUser failing to connect to remote sql server

Tags: asp.net-membership, remote-server

I've got an ASP.NET app that uses the standard SQL Server Membership provider to authenticate. Works fine with a local database (this is NOT SQL Svr Express!). When I try to authenticate against a remote database, even with correct connection string, I always get a 'Named Pipes Provider, error 40: Could not open a connection to SQL Server. I've verified that the server allows remote connections and that it supports Named Pipes connections. No one else is using the database at the same time (although others may be connected to the server). Here is the connection string and membership info in my web.config (names dummied and ip address dummied for privacy). Any one have any ideas?
  Bob

(same settings as above for roleManager)

Comment: You forgot to paste the connection strings as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Named pipe is valid for local connection only. Need TCP Protocol.